# How can I convert CSS linear gradient to JS code in React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, styling, linear-gradients

I have the input data in CSS from Figma, and I don't know how to rewrite it to make it work in react native, are there any libraries that can help me, and if yes, how could I write it?
The CSS code is here:

[image]

Comment: If you search for React Native Linear Gradient you'll get some tutorials, documentation and similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with CSS in react native. I used something called react-native-gradient.

This is their Github

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

You could use expo too (if you're on expo cli)

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/

Hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package called react-native-linear-gradient
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient

and also for width and height use Dimensions of the window
like Dimension.get("window").height/width
refer https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions